# How hard is finding values such that

Tags: intuition, exponentiation, finite-fields

We can work with powers of some naturals $(x_k)^{m_k}$.  Here we have $n$ naturals, and $m_k$ is an integer in the range $-r$ to $r$.  My question is, how small can $p$ be so that

$$\prod_{k=1}^n{(x_k)^{m_k}}$$

is unique for any collection of $m_k$'s?  In other words, for any set of $k$ integers of one's choosing, how small can we make $p$ so that the product above is always unique?  The answer doesn't have to be perfect.  Even a general idea would be good.

**AN EXAMPLE**

Let $n=2$.

Then we can pick $x_1=2$ and $x_2=3$, and find that $p=31$ works.  We could choose any $x$'s we like, in order to get a smaller $p$.

and here's a table of powers:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\times & 2^{-2} & 2^{-1} & 2^0 & 2^1 & 2^2 \\
\hline
3^{-2} & 25 &  19 &  7 & 14 & 28 \\
\hline
3^{-1} & 13 & 26 & 21 & 11 & 22\\
\hline
3^0 & 8 & 16 & 1 & 2 & 4\\
\hline
3^1 & 24 & 17 & 3 & 6 & 12 \\
\hline
3^2 & 10 & 20 & 9 & 18 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So by picking the $x$'s carefully, we have made sure that all powers from $-2$ to $2$ for both numbers is unique.  And this then works for $p=31$, as shown.

**THE QUESTION, AGAIN**

We're given $n$ and $r$, and wish to solve for $p$.

So if we have $n$ values of $x$ (of our choosing - they're not given - they can help make the problem easier), and we are interested in all powers between $-r$ and $r$, how small can $p$ be?

**ANOTHER TIDBIT**

I'm wondering if this would be considered research-level mathematics.  Perhaps someone can answer this?

Comment: Your introduction seems to imply you're minimizing $p$, but in your example $p$ is given. And are you supposed to find $p$ such that for *all* choices of $(x_i)$ the condition holds-or are the $x_i$ fixed as well? If the $(x_i)$ have to vary I think the problem is generally impossible; otherwise if $p$ is given then I think it's probably solvable for basically any $r$ less that $p^2$, whereas if only $(x_i)$ $n$ and $r$ are given it's probably not that easy. In any case, why are you interested?

Comment: @KevinCarlson:  $p$ isn't given - only $n$ and $r$ are given.  I'm asking because it will help determine how fast an algorithm runs.  But your interpretation may help - perhaps we can keep picking $p$ (and then solving for $n$ and $r$) until we find a $p$ that works for the given $n$ and $r$.

Comment: I still don't quite understand whether you need to find $p$ depending on $n$ and $r$ such that for given $x_i$ or for arbitrary $x_i$ your condition holds.

Comment: @KevinCarlson:  The $x_i$ are arbitrary.  Pick whatever $x_i$ you want!  I tried to edit the question to show this.  I'm also thinking that you may mean it's probably solvable for any $r$ less than $p^n$, since I mean that there are $n$ of the $x$ values in the problem.  Also, just a quick note:  I found that if we have $r=2$ and $n=2$ we can set $x_1=2$ and $x_1=3$ and it will work for $p=29$.

Comment: Currently, I'd be happy if we could show that show that $p \in r^{O(n)}$, or even better, show that $p \le (r^{c \cdot n})$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Is your product supposed to be taken $\pmod p$?  It appears so.

Comment: @RossMillikan:  Yes.

Comment: In your example, you can even accommodate $3^3$ as well and get $30$ different numbers

Comment: As there are $(2r+1)^n$ entries in your table, $p$ has to be at least that large.

Comment: @RossMillikan:  Yeah, I know we need at least $(2r+1)^n$.  The problem is I don't really have any good ideas to do any better than the baseline answer I give.  Just from experimenting with values in Mathematica, it seems like we can get pretty close to this with just a few tries.  But again, I don't have any good ideas on how to do the analysis.

Comment: I just tried $r=2, p=127, x=2,3,5$ and it fails because $2^43^35\equiv 1 \pmod {127}$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Hmm.  I'd suggest trying to multiply $p$ by some small number.  I tried $n=r=3$ and $p=2003$ and it worked- there are 343 different values for this scenario.  My guess from this is that finding $p$ should only take a few tries if $p>(2r+1)^{2n}$.

Comment: If we are allowed to choose the integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, then why wouldn't the following work. Let $p$ be a bit larger than $(2r+1)^n$. Let $g$ be a primitive root. Then we know that the powers $g^i, 0\le i<p-1$ are all pairwise incongruent modulo $p$.  Then let $x_1=g$, $x_2\equiv g^{2r+1}\pmod p$, $x_3\equiv x_2^{2r+1}\pmod p$ et cetera. This should prevent the collisions, because $\prod_i x_i^{m_i}$ can be viewed as
$g^\ell$ with $\ell=\sum_i m_i(2r+1)^{i-1}$, and those are all distinct modulo $p-1$ (I think).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Great idea!  I can't think of a good reason why that wouldn't work.  I think I got stuck looking at the problem from a certain perspective; at least that's my excuse.  I also can't think of a good reason why I wouldn't accept this as an answer, if you want to type it up.  Either way, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out my comment to an answer/suggestion.

Let's first look at an additive version. We know that that the sums
$$
S(m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1}):=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}m_k(2r+1)^{k-1},
$$
with all the $m_k$ ranging over $\{-r,-r+1,\ldots,-1,0,1,\ldots,r-1,r\}$, are distinct (sorta like writing integers in base $2r+1$) and in the interval from $-\left((2r+1)^n-1\right)/2$ to $\left((2r+1)^n-1\right)/2$, i.e. of length $<(2r+1)^n$.

Next we proceed to map this to the domain of modular multiplication. To that end let us pick a prime $p>(2r+1)^n$. Further let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. It is well known that $g^i\equiv g^j\pmod p$ if and only if $i\equiv j\pmod{p-1}$. Therefore all the powers $g^{S(m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1})}$ are pairwise non-congruent modulo $p$.

This implies that the choice $x_i=g^{(2r+1)^{i-1}}$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ fulfills Matt's requirements. This is because
$$
\prod_{k=1}^nx_k^{m_k}\equiv g^{S(m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1})}\pmod p.
$$

As an example consider the case $n=2$, $r=3$. Now $(2r+1)^2=49$, so we can select $p=53$. It is easy to show that $g=2$ is a primitive root, so we select $x_1=2$. We further select $x_2=22$ as $x_1^7=128\equiv22\pmod{53}$. As a final confirmation let me represent the table of remainders of $2^i\cdot 22^j$ modulo $53$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
i\backslash j&-3&-2&-1&0&1&2&3\\
\hline\\
-3&49& 18& 25& 20& 16& 34& 6\\
-2&45& 36& 50& 40& 32& 15& 12\\
-1&37& 19& 47& 27& 11& 30& 24\\
0&21& 38& 41& 1& 22& 7& 48\\
1&42& 23& 29& 2& 44& 14& 43\\
2&31& 46& 5& 4& 35& 28& 33\\
3&9&39& 10& 8& 17& 3& 13
\end{array}
$$

As an example with $n=3$, $r=2$, $(2r+1)^n=125$ we use $p=127$. This time we can use $x_1=g=3$, $x_2=116\equiv 3^5\pmod{127}$ and $x_3=112\equiv x_2^5\pmod{127}$. I hope I can be excused for failing to provide the resulting 3-dimensional table of 125 entries.

It is clear that the density of prime numbers is high enough so that we need not go much above the limit $(2r+1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here' sort of a baseline answer.  It doesn't provide a very good bounds, but we can prove it works.  Please pardon my description, as I know it could be a lot better.  Any suggestions that will improve this are welcome.

So we start with $n$ values, and we want to ensure they're unique when we use the given function in the question.

We also start knowing the powers range from $-r$ to $r$.  This means that we'll be using $2r + 1$ powers of each number.

So, we can start by choosing the $x$ values to be the $n$ smallest primes.  Then we know that we'll have each $x$ value range from $x^{-r}$ to $x^r$, inclusive.  We temporarily change this range of powers to be from $x^0$ to $x^{2r}$, inclusive, which will give us $2r + 1$ powers.

Then if we pick a prime that is greater than

$$\prod_{k=1}^n{(x_k)^{2r}} = (x_1)^{2r} \cdot (x_2)^{2r} \cdot (x_3)^{2r}\dots (x_n)^{2r} \tag{1}$$

...all of these new powers are guaranteed to be unique.  That is because the factorization of each number in this form is unique from any other number of this form, since we are using primes.  In other words, we have created a unique factorization by using this form.

Now, since we are working modulo a prime, and hence also working with a finite field, we know that we can multiply by $(x_k)^{-r}$ for any $x^k$ and the values in the above function will still be unique.

Thus we can now multiply all of the values in the above function by:

$$\prod_{k=1}^n{(x_k)^{-r}} = (x_1)^{-r} \cdot (x_2)^{-r} \cdot (x_3)^{-r}\dots (x_n)^{-r} \tag{2}$$

And this will give us the function for our original range.  Thus we have proved that we can get the unique values that we are after by picking ANY $p$ such that $p$ is prime and greater than Equation (1).